# The lattice equivalent of geom_tile when displaying text

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, lattice

I am interested in knowing if there is a lattice alternative to `geom_tile()` in ggplot2 when I want to display factor levels/map fill to text. Example data frame (`df`) follows...

```
Gene Sample Mutation
A1    2       Missense
A2    2       WT
A1    3       Missense
A2    3       Missense
```

With ggplot2 this is trivial

```
qplot(df, y=Gene, x=Sample, fill=Mutation, geom='tile')
```

what would the lattice equivalent of this be? (I am interested in this because axis alignment in ggplot2 between plots is convoluted and cumbersome currently).

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A1",  "A2"), class = "factor"), 
                     Sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L ), .Label = c("2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
                     Mutation = structure(c(1L,  2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Missense", "WT"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gene",  "Sample", "Mutation"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me: `> qplot(df, y=Gene, x=Sample, fill=Mutation, geom='tile')
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Mutation' not found`

Comment: That is because you need to create df first... here is the code to generate it, extracted using dput()

     `structure(list(Gene = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A1", 
"A2"), class = "factor"), Sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("2", "3"), class = "factor"), Mutation = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Missense", "WT"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gene", 
"Sample", "Mutation"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Don't you think I created `df` first!? I'm no idiot, as one look at my rep/profile will show. I recreated `df` from the pasted information and the `qplot()` call you show doesn't work for me, giving the error shown.

Comment: It still doesn't work...

Comment: It works for me - clearly does. I could only assume that the object hasn't been created if it wouldn't detect a column that is part of it.

[link] http://i917.photobucket.com/albums/ad11/AnkyChakravarthy/screenshot_zpsf9683b98.jpg [link]

Comment: The code is failing for me with `ggplot2_1.0.0` installed - I just updated things and started in a clean session. Your `sessionInfo()` says what version you are using?

Comment: The same version as yours: ggplot2_1.0.0 while on R 3.1.0

Comment: I got a series of errors because the column names were not quoted. @GavinSimpson: My guess is that that Ankur also had individual arguments that were being pulled into the evaluation environment when the character names were not being found by `qplot`s rather-non-standard evaluation mechanism. I'm also thinking the request might be fore a heatmap equivalent in lattice.

Comment: @BondedDust - not quite a heatmap equivalent - for levelplot does that pretty well when you've got numerical data to render - the trouble I am having is with mapping character/text factor levels to colours like geom_tile can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `levelplot()` function in **lattice**, for example

```
library("lattice")
df <- transform(df, Sample = factor(Sample))
levelplot(Mutation ~ Gene * Sample, data = df)
```

You'll need to work out the colour scale key yourself though.